# Create a horizontal menu in Extjs

Tags: extjs

How to create a horizontal menu in Extjs ?

Example vertical menu :

```
Ext.onReady(function(){ 
    var menu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        margin: '0 0 10 0',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        floating: false,
        items: [{
            text: 'JavaScript',
        },{
            text: 'Java'
        },{
            text: 'C/C++'
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [layout property(examples)](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html)

```
Ext.onReady(function(){ 
    var menu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
        layout: 'hbox',
        width: 300,
        height: 100,
        margin: '0 0 10 0',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        floating: false,
        items: [{
            text: 'JavaScript',
        },{
            text: 'Java'
        },{
            text: 'C/C++'
        }]
    });
});
```